# laravel updateOrCreate change data depends on event

Tags: laravel

i am using laravel updateOrCreate function

```
$variable = Variable::updateOrCreate(
            ['name' => $name,
            'landing_id' => $landing_id,
            'version_id' => $version_id,
            'page_id' => $page_id],
            [
             'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
             'user_modified_id' => Auth::user()->id ]
        );
```

how to use this function properly that when record is created add value to user_id and when record is updated user_modified_id would be updated.

```
Well i found work around for my issue but i don't know if this is best way to do. What i have to do is this: 
            if( $variable->user_id == 0){
                $variable->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            }

            $variable->value = $setting;
            $variable->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use below code to perform your data. The first indicates the conditions for a match and second is used to specify which fields to update.

```html
$variable = Variable::updateOrCreate([
    //Add unique field combo to match here
    //For example, perhaps you only want one entry per user:
    'user_id'   => Auth::user()->id,
],[
    'name'       => $name,
    'landing_id' => $landing_id,
    'version_id' => $version_id,
    'page_id'    => $page_id
]);
```

Definitely nicer this way.

Comment: well my given example shows that i want to create or update a databse row by 4 columns and on create add user who created row and on update add user who updated it. Your example no good for what i am looking for, but thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable = Variable::updateOrCreate(
        ['name' => $name,
        'landing_id' => $landing_id,
        'version_id' => $version_id,
        'page_id' => $page_id],
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
        [
         'user_modified_id' => Auth::user()->id ]
    );
```

The first array will create a new model if there is no match, the second array will update the specified values if exist.

Your problem is that `user_modified_id` will be created alongside with `user_id` if there is no records matching.